# выводит 00000060B913F990 вместо массива

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "оценки первой недели";
    string week1[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cin >>week1[i];
    }`
    cout <<week1;
}
```

Comment: Выводите массив поэлементно. Как и вводите :) Так вы выводите адрес первого элемента массива (грубо, где в памяти начинается массив).

Comment: а в каком виде ожидается вывод массива и почему?

Answer (score 0):

В C++ нельзя просто вывести массив. Но можно циклом вывести его элементы, например так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    cout << week1[i] << ' ';
```